# IntelliJ equivalent of Eclipse's "Quick Switch Editor"?

Tags: intellij-idea

Eclipse has a very useful command called "Quick Switch Editor" which lets you switch between open editor tabs by typing the name of the tab (and it does fuzzy matching too). It's great if you're like me and you habitually have 50+ tabs open. Is it possible to do this in IntelliJ, either built-in or with a plugin?

Comment: I usually open a file (Ctrl-Shift-N) or a class (Ctrl-N) without caring if a tab containing this file/class is already opened.

Comment: When you have tens or hundreds of thousands of files and classes available, the ability to move specifically to one that's open is quite useful.

Comment: When using Ctrl+E you can also do "fuzzy matching" as you mentioned.

Comment: No upvotes? What a shame. Life saver question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> you'll get the following popup window:

[image]

And in this window you can do searches by just starting to type:

[image]

Comment: Eek, I always had my emacs-like `CTRL-X B` mapped to "Switcher", which does not provide the incremental search. Using "Recent Files" instead for `CTRL-X B` is just great.

Answer (score 1):

try `Alt+Right` or `Alt+Left` or Press `Ctrl+Tab`

Comment: CTRL-TAB ... the thing that gets you the switcher on MacOs! Great tip!